# can't get bitmap of image using Picasso target on intentservice when app is not running

Tags: android, notifications, alarmmanager, picasso, intentservice

this code is for show bigpicture style notification when alarm manager triggers alarm and the bigpicture image have to download from internet using picasso and intentservice even when the app is not running in foreground or background but working fine when app is running in foreground or background

i got notification with image downloaded from  internet when app is in foreground and also in background 
     Check the video for understanding the problem please mute audio because its very noisy

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ID3PLuBvaRE&t=35s

```
class ShowNotificationFromAlarm : IntentService("ShowNotificationFromAlarm") {

    var target = object : Target {
        override fun onPrepareLoad(placeHolderDrawable: Drawable?) {
            Log.d("alarmnoti", "onprepareload")
        }

        override fun onBitmapFailed(errorDrawable: Drawable?) {
            Log.d("alarmnoti", "bitmapfailed")
        }

        override fun onBitmapLoaded(bitmap: Bitmap?, from: Picasso.LoadedFrom?) {
            Log.d("alarmnoti", "bitmaploaded")
            val builder = Notification.Builder(this@ShowNotificationFromAlarm)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_share)
                    .setContentTitle(this@ShowNotificationFromAlarm.getString(R.string.app_name))
                    .setContentText("this is text")
                    .setLargeIcon(bitmap)
                    .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL)
                    .setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_HIGH) //must give priority to High, Max which will considered as heads-up notification
                    .setStyle(Notification.BigPictureStyle()
                            .setBigContentTitle("this is big content title")
                            .setSummaryText("this is summary text")
                            .bigPicture(bitmap)
                    )

            //.addAction(action)
            val notification = builder.build()
            NotificationManagerCompat.from(this@ShowNotificationFromAlarm).notify(100, notification)
        }
    }

    override fun onHandleIntent(intent: Intent?) {    
        Log.d(this.packageName + "\t intentservice", "intent started")

        if (intent != null) {
            val uiHandler = Handler(Looper.getMainLooper())
            uiHandler.post(Runnable {
                shownotification(this@ShowNotificationFromAlarm.applicationContext, intent)
            })
        }
    }

    private fun shownotification(context: Context, intent: Intent) {    
        val intent = Intent(context, MainActivity::class.java)
        val pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, System.currentTimeMillis().toInt(), intent, 0)    
        Picasso.with(context)
                .load("https://cartodb-basemaps-d.global.ssl.fastly.net/dark_nolabels/3/3/4.png")
                //.load(context.filesDir.absolutePath + File.pathSeparator+"logo-2.png")
                .into(target)
    }
}
```

Comment: Add breakpoint at line `onBitmapLoaded` and confirm value of `bitmap`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using **IntentService** which is already runs on separate thread.You can directly download image instead of pushing the downloading task into other thread. See the code below.

```
public class DownloadClass extends IntentService{
public DownloadClass(String name) {
    super(name);
}

@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(@Nullable Intent intent) {
    String url =intent.getStringExtra("url");
    Bitmap bitmap=downloadImageBitmap(url);
    if(bitmap!=null){
        // Use bitmap here
    }
}

private Bitmap downloadImageBitmap(String sUrl) {
    Bitmap bitmap = null;
    try {
        InputStream inputStream = new URL(sUrl).openStream();   // Download Image from URL
        bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);       // Decode Bitmap
        inputStream.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return bitmap;
}
}
```

Comment: My bad  . Concept is the same . You can give it a try . let me know if it works .

Comment: yes thank you very much ..............:)  it worked bro thanks but i modified the little 
i write the notification within try block 
because the image have to download and may take some time

Comment: Ok. Thx.Read about intent service to get more of it .

Comment: k sure , i have to gain more knowledge on intent service
have a good day